# I'm trying to run a flutter app but this happens when running gradle task 'assemblyDebug'. How can I get past this

Tags: android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.50/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar'.
> > Connection reset
> Could not download fastutil.jar (it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.jar'.
> > Connection reset

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22m 42s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1